# Can a server mess up my current operation by sending another message?

Tags: websocket, server

I wonder, let's assume I have a server (websocket server if that's important) and I need to know whenever I receive a message and start processing it, does another received message wait until my current function is done running or does it run in parallel?

Comment: Hi Franciszek. Please post some code so folks can understand the context of what you are trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Come on. Is it hard to understand? Firstly, I'm getting once message. I'm processing it (executing a function to parse incoming packet), and there lies my question. If another message is delivered WHILE I am still parsing previous packet, does the second, newest message wait until the parsing function is finished or does it just invoke another function, being parsed in parallel to the first message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks some information about the WebSocket **client**, so I will make assumptions.

If you're running the **WebSocket client in the browser**, using the browser's JavaScript engine, then the answer is "yes".

JavaScript runs on a single thread. The next WebSocket message will wait for the current event to finish processing before the next event (i.e., the WebSocket message) could be processed.

However, if you're running your own WebSocket client, this behavior might be different, as it is client specific.